# Javamail ignore socks proxy when ssl is enabled

Tags: java, email, ssl, proxy

I've setup javamail to run through a socks proxy with ssl, but it won't go through it. I tried setting both mail.smtp.socks.host and mail.smtp.socks.port but it keeps going direct to the mail host. Here's my properties:

```
    smtpProps = new Properties();
    smtpProps.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", sendHost);
    smtpProps.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", String.valueOf(sendPort));
    smtpProps.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtps");
    smtpProps.setProperty("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "true");
    smtpProps.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    smtpProps.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "true");
    smtpProps.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    smtpProps.setProperty("mail.smtp.connectiontimeout", String.valueOf(sendConnTimeout) ); 
    smtpProps.setProperty("mail.smtp.writetimeout", String.valueOf(sendTimeout) );

    smtpProps.setProperty("mail.smtp.socks.host", proxyHost);
    smtpProps.setProperty("mail.smtp.socks.port", String.valueOf(proxyPort));

    smtpProps.setProperty("mail.debug", "true");
    smtpProps.setProperty("mail.socket.debug", "true");
```

I've tried all smtp**s** property name combination without any success. I'm using Java 7 and javamail 1.4.7. 
The only one workaround I found for now is to use a custom version of SSL socket factory

```
     smtpProps.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", 
        proxied?
            "my.socks.ProxiedSSLSocketFactory" :
                "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
```

` 
obviously I can't use system properties socksProxyHost & socksProxyPort. 
Any ideas?

Comment: Did you found an answer? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: The only one solution I found was JavaMail version 1.4.7. This is the first version that correctly handles socks & ssl.